# Python import method from another module's class

Tags: python, oop, methods, import, module

I'm trying to use a method from a class in one of my methods in another file but i am receiving an error

```
#File 2
class Database():
    def __init__(self,loggedIn):
        self.loggedIn = False

def login(self,username, password):
        conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
        cur=conn.cursor()
        find_user = ("SELECT * FROM customerDetails WHERE email = ? AND 
        password = ?")
        cur.execute(find_user, [(username), (password)])
        results = cur.fetchall()

#File 1
login = Database.login(username_text.get(),password2_text.get())
```

NameError: name 'Database' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

As one of the first lines in `file1.py`, do:

`from file2 import Database`

Otherwise, it has no notion of what `Database` is or where it comes from.

This is assuming your filenames are `file1.py` and `file2.py`.